# How to fix PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library?

Tags: php, xampp, lamp, ini, igbinary

when trying to install igbinary to xampp v3.2.2

downloaded dll from this link https://pecl.php.net/package/igbinary/2.0.1/windows

getting this below error, surprisingly  php_igbinary.dll exist in 'C:\xampp\php\ext\' then why this error? any help?

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\igbinary.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right DLL file was not placed for PHP version 7.4.0 once i placed the right version for igbinary DLL file in to PHP/ext folder, issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows and XAMP you have to use the Thread  Safe version (TS) the other one aren't working. And you have to be patient, that it is only available to PHP 7.1. Here is another explanation:

https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary/issues/246

Comment: Not only that... you'd have to have the suitable PHP build version and compiler version tags, or the extension won't load either. And don't forget: a 32bit extension won't run on 64bit PHP and vice versa...

Comment: Yes right there are much more things that can go wrong. But there are only a few download options :D so if this is not working you have to compile it.

Comment: but when release not says it's Compatible with PHP 5.2 - 5.6  then why not? https://pecl.php.net/package/igbinary/1.2.1